# Where can I download (or buy) a database of Chess960 games?

Tags: database, chess960

Where can I download (or buy) a database of Chess960 games? Or at least find games from the major Chess960 tournaments?

edit:
If some is interested [here](http://yadi.sk/d/F_uaAtqyMJVFd) are games I managed to find in internet.

Comment: Found a blog on Chess960, http://chess960jungle.blogspot.se/

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question, and the answer is little bit funny.

Guess where I found these games, would you?

On chessgames.com! But it's not called Chess960, nor Fischer's chess, nor random chess, it's called: [Chess variants (000)](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessopening?eco=000)

If you go to to [ChessBase Database](http://database.chessbase.com/js/apps/onlinedb/) and you enter in the search form `chess960` you will find many games.

**EDIT**

I emailed [365Chess.com](http://365Chess.com) and [Chesstempo.com](http://chesstempo.com) and they said they don't have Chess960 games, I emailed [Chessgames.com](http://chessgames.com) and they replied.

> There are a couple of them.  There’s no easy way to pull them up, but
>   [here is a collection with 3.](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1008874)
>
> There might be one or two more.

I guess I did a better job than Chessgames team at finding chess960 games in their own database :)

I emailed [Chess.com](http://Chess.com), they said

> Thanks for your email. Unfortunately we don't have a database of
>   Chess960 games available for download. Premium members of Chess.com
>   have access to all the Chess960 games played on Chess.com.

Comment: It seems that Fischer Random is only a subset of the games that are marked as Chess Variants 000. So this is not a pure Chess960 collection. Moreover, it seems a bit difficult to filter out Chess960 games in this collection. Yet, if this is indeed one of the few online sources, then perhaps with a bit of support from the chess community, it could grow over time.

Comment: @RauanSagit yes you are right, I'm going to email all the major chess databases out there and see if they give me some resources

Comment: @RauanSagit I updated my answer, and I emailed some websites, if I receive some new information, I will update it again

Comment: The ChessBase online database was a real surprise! I had no idea it existed! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Go here:

[AjedrezPeru](http://ajedrezperu.info/partidas/bases-de-datos)

you can found a one million database with the most important games in PGN format, so you can import all of them in your software.

Comment: I don't think those are Chess960.